# Which @Scope should I choose for a stateful(?) @Service

Tags: spring, scope

I'm new to Spring.

I'm working on a library project which depends on `spring-context`.

```
@Scope(value = "@@?")
@Service
public class MyService {

    @PostConstruct private void constructed() {
    }

    @PreDestroying private void destroying() {
        resource.clear();
    }

    public void doSome() throws IOException {
        // try{}finally{} is not the case
        resource = getSome();
        doSome(resource); // may throw an IOException
        resource.clear();
    }

    private transient MyResource resource;
}
```

I want to free the `resource` in every time this instance being destroyed.

According to [@Scope](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Scope.html), there four options that I can choose.

- [ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/ConfigurableBeanFactory.html#SCOPE_SINGLETON)
- [ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/ConfigurableBeanFactory.html#SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
- [WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext.html#SCOPE_REQUEST)
- [WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext.html#SCOPE_SESSION)

I found that `WebApplicationContext` is not available from my dependency tree. (I'm not depends on `spring-webmvc`)

I'm planning to choose [ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/ConfigurableBeanFactory.html#SCOPE_PROTOTYPE).

Is it true that the scope I choose will make MyService safe? I mean any two or more clients can't be injected with the same service instance? Will the Spring container take care of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, `Request`, `Session`, `Global-session` and `Application` scopes are only available within Web aware application context.

`Singleton` (single instance *per Spring* container) is a default scope used by Spring, so using prototype scope will guarantee that new instance will be created and returned to the client, so yes `Prototype` is what you need in this case.